# Getting Error about arguments in constructor while trying to test a constructor with NUnit

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, nunit

I have a bank account class. We're learning on how to test your constructors and objects and methods using NUnit.

This is my BankAccount class.

```
    using System;
namespace PT7BankSim
{
    public class BankAccount
    {
        private int _accNumber;
        private double _balance;
        private AccountType _type;

        public int AccNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _accNumber;
            }
        }

        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return _balance;
            }
        }



        public BankAccount(int accNum, AccountType type)
        {
            _balance = 0.00;
            _accNumber = accNum;
            _type = type;

        }

        public void Deposit(double amt)
        {
            _balance += amt;
        }

        public void Withdraw(double amt)
        {
            if (amt > _balance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n Insufficient Balance in account: " + _accNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                _balance -= amt;
            }

        }

        public String Details()
        {
            String sDetails = _type + " Account" + "         : " + _accNumber + " Balance : " + _balance;
            return sDetails;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my "TestClass", I am supposed to test the constructor of BankAccount

```
    using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace PT7BankSim
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestBank
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestConstructor()
        {
            BankAccount TBA = new BankAccount();
            Assert.AreEqual(00, TBA.AccNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I just randomly test out 1 value/parameter and the IDE gives me an error saying **"there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter accNum of BankAccount.BankAccount(int,AccountType)"**

Why is this giving this error and how to solve it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a parameterless constructor, when your BankAccount class doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Either create a parameterless constructor in your BankAccount class, or correctly pass arguments into new BankAccount();